# Regular expression

Tags: regex, oracle

Need to replace this string

> 'Acute Tox. 4 ;H302|Eye Irrit. 2A;H319'

with this

> 'Acute Tox. 4 (H302)|Eye Irrit. 2A;(H319)'

Basically I need to put all *H* codes in parentheses.

I tried:

```
select REGEXP_replace('Acute Tox. 4 ;H302|Eye Irrit. 2A;H319',';H\d{3}','(H') from dual;
```

but that results in:

```
Acute Tox. 4 (H|Eye Irrit. 2A(H
```

Comment: I tried select REGEXP_replace('Acute Tox. 4 ;H302|Eye Irrit. 2A;H319',';H\d{3}','(H')
from dual; but that does not work

Comment: Questions are rarely clear when they are expressed in terms of an example. Examples are intended to illustrate a precise and unambiguous statement of the question; they are not a substitute for the latter. Here the pattern to match is not evident. Must `'H'` be preceded by a `';'`? Must the last digit be followed by `'|'` or be at the end of the string? Must there be exactly three digits following `'H'`? Can the first digit be `'0'`?...

Comment: ...If the answers are all 'yes', you could state your question thusly: "I wish to replace all 4-characters strings of the form `'Hddd'`, where `d` represents any digit, with `'(Hddd)'`, provided `'H'` is preceded by `';'` and the last digit is followed by `'|'` or is at the end of the string. For example, ....

Comment: Your comment should be part of the question. Please edit. "that does not work" is vague and needs to be clarified. To highlight parts of text (e.g., `H302`), surround it with backticks (`\``). To highlight one or more lines of text (e.g., inputs, code or results) indent it 4 spaces or select it and click on '{}' above the edit box. Lastly, the line following, `"but that results in:"` is a string, so it should be surrounded by quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
select REGEXP_replace('Acute Tox. 4 ;H302|Eye Irrit. 2A;H319',';(H\d{3})',';(\1)') from dual;
```

Comment: Your regex will only capture a code with a length of 3.  May I suggest this change, which tightens up the match by capturing any length numeric code, plus the following character, be it the delimiter or the end of the line: `REGEXP_REPLACE('Acute Tox. 4 ;H388802|Eye Irrit. 2A;H3', ';(H\d+)(\||$)', ';(\1)\2')`.  Maybe overkill, but it will ensure you will not grab an erroneous letter followed by numbers should it be part of the description before the code.

Comment: @Gary_W Based on OP's attempt they only want to capture the letter `H` followed by 3 digits; maybe it's only a valid H code if it has 3 digits. They could be actively ignoring rogue things like `H5`

Comment: I see that now, thank you.  I think i still have a good point though.

Comment: @Gary_W OPs post leaves a lot of information to be desired. They claim my solution works so if there are edge cases and other missteps then it's OP's problem now :-)

Comment: Yes the H is followed by 3 digits only.  @Gary_W you have a valid point.